# How to make (best way) specific custom Symfony 2 form element type?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I need to create form element with following logic:

- User need to select his budget for something
- He can select it with radio button
- or select "Other" and enter it manualy

Here is HTML markup that represents this logic:

```
Choose your budget:
<div id="briefing_budget" class="budget clearfix">
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="briefing_budget_0" name="briefing[budget][selected]" required="required" value="9999"> 9 999 rubles
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="briefing[budget][selected]" value="other"> other <input type="text" name="briefing[budget][number]">
</label>
</div>
```

To make this work, I've created custom field type with custom Twig block. Finnaly, I've got something that I don't really like...

Here is the code of custom type:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Optimal\PromoAction\FreeCampaignFor10k;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\LogicException;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\SimpleChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\ChoiceToBooleanArrayTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\EventListener\FixRadioInputListener;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;


/**
 * choices : [{"<value>": "<label>"}]
 */
class NumberRadioType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * Caches created choice lists.
     * @var array
     */
    private $choiceListCache = array();

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        if (!$options['choice_list'] && !is_array($options['choices']) && !$options['choices'] instanceof \Traversable) {
            throw new LogicException('Either the option "choices" or "choice_list" must be set.');
        }

        $preferredViews = $options['choice_list']->getPreferredViews();
        $remainingViews = $options['choice_list']->getRemainingViews();

        if (null !== $options['empty_value'] && 0 === count($options['choice_list']->getChoicesForValues(array('')))) {
            $placeholderView = new ChoiceView(null, '', $options['empty_value']);

            $this->addSubForms($builder, array('placeholder' => $placeholderView), $options);
        }

        $this->addSubForms($builder, $preferredViews, $options);
        $this->addSubForms($builder, $remainingViews, $options);


        $builder->addViewTransformer(new ChoiceToBooleanArrayTransformer($options['choice_list'], $builder->has('placeholder')));
        $builder->addEventSubscriber(new FixRadioInputListener($options['choice_list'], $builder->has('placeholder')), 10);

        $name = $builder->getName();
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($name) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $data = $data['selected'] == 'other' ? $data['number'] : $data['selected'];
            $event->setData($data);
        });

    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, array(
            'preferred_choices' => $options['choice_list']->getPreferredViews(),
            'choices' => $options['choice_list']->getRemainingViews(),
            'separator' => '-------------------',
            'empty_value' => null,
        ));

        $view->vars['is_selected'] = function ($choice, $value) {
            return $choice === $value;
        };

        $view->vars['empty_value_in_choices'] = 0 !== count($options['choice_list']->getChoicesForValues(array('')));

        if (null !== $options['empty_value'] && !$view->vars['empty_value_in_choices']) {
            $view->vars['empty_value'] = $options['empty_value'];
        }


    }

    public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($view as $childView) {
            $childView->vars['full_name'] = $view->vars['full_name'] . '[selected]';
        }
    }


    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $choiceListCache =& $this->choiceListCache;

        $choiceList = function (Options $options) use (&$choiceListCache) {
            $choices = null !== $options['choices'] ? $options['choices'] : array();

            // Reuse existing choice lists in order to increase performance
            $hash = hash('sha256', json_encode(array($choices, $options['preferred_choices'])));

            if (!isset($choiceListCache[$hash])) {
                $choiceListCache[$hash] = new SimpleChoiceList($choices, $options['preferred_choices']);
            }

            return $choiceListCache[$hash];
        };

        $emptyData = array();

        $emptyValue = function (Options $options) {
            return $options['required'] ? null : '';
        };

        $emptyValueNormalizer = function (Options $options, $emptyValue) {
            if (false === $emptyValue) {
                return;
            } elseif ('' === $emptyValue) {
                return 'None';
            }

            return $emptyValue;
        };

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choice_list' => $choiceList,
            'choices' => array(),
            'preferred_choices' => array(),
            'empty_data' => $emptyData,
            'empty_value' => $emptyValue,
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'compound' => true,
            'data_class' => null,
        ));

        $resolver->setNormalizers(array(
            'empty_value' => $emptyValueNormalizer,
        ));

        $resolver->setAllowedTypes(array(
            'choice_list' => array('null', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceListInterface'),
        ));
    }


    /**
     * Returns the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string The name of this type
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'number_radio';
    }

    /**
     * Adds the sub fields for an expanded choice field.
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder The form builder.
     * @param array $choiceViews The choice view objects.
     * @param array $options The build options.
     */
    private function addSubForms(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $choiceViews, array $options)
    {
        foreach ($choiceViews as $i => $choiceView) {
            if (is_array($choiceView)) {
                // Flatten groups
                $this->addSubForms($builder, $choiceView, $options);
            } else {
                $choiceOpts = array(
                    'value' => $choiceView->value,
                    'label' => $choiceView->label,
                    'translation_domain' => $options['translation_domain'],
                );


                $choiceType = 'radio';


                $builder->add($i, $choiceType, $choiceOpts);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And template:

```
{% block number_radio_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {% for child in form %}
                        <label>{{ form_widget(child) }}{{ child.vars.label }}</label>
                {% endfor %}
                <label><input type="radio" name="{{ form.vars.full_name }}[selected]" value="other"/>
                    other <input type="text" name="{{ form.vars.full_name }}[number]"/>
                </label>
            </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm newbie in Symfony, so I copypasted a lot from Symfony's class `ChoiceType`, and actualy don't know purpose of half of stuff that happens there. :)

Finnaly, the question is: **What is the best (or at least better) way to achieve what I have had achieved using Symfony 2 form component?**

Comment: Please consider editing this question to ask "is there a Symphony-specific way to handle this form component with less code?

Answer (score 1):

If you heritate the FormType from "text", it will be much simple to handle with some javascript added in twig

Set the minimum required in the form type :

```
class NumberRadioType  extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->setAttribute('configs', $options['configs']);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['configs'] = $form->getConfig()->getAttribute('configs');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'configs' => array()
        ));

        $resolver->setNormalizers(array(
            'configs' => function (Options $options, $value) {
                return true;
            }
        ));
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */    
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'NumberRadio';
    }
```

in html twig template as you did :

```
{% block number_radio_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
            <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
                {% for child in form %}
                        <label>{{ form_widget(child) }}{{ child.vars.label }}</label>
                {% endfor %}
                <label><input type="radio" {{id}}/>
                    other <input type="text" name="{{ form.vars.full_name }}[number]" value="{{value}}"/>
                </label>
            </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

you can use **{{id}}** to get the parameter of an input like the name, id and value

you can use **{{value}}** to get the value of the input

in javascript twig template, you can customize your component

```
{% block number_radio_javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedInput = $('input[name=briefing[budget][selected]]:checked', '#myForm').val()
if(selectedInput ==1){
//do something
}else{
//do something else
}

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

You ll need to add some code to include the javascript part. Have a look to "genemu form" to learn how to do, but basicaly : 
you need to create a twig extension

https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle/blob/master/Twig/Extension/FormExtension.php

then use the extension each time to use your formType

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block jsscript %}
{{ vendor_type_javascript(form) }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_rest(edit_form) }}
{% endblock %}
```